# How to add page numbers to a table header?

Tags: java, itext

I have created a PdfPTable (with a header) that is split over several pages. I use ColumnText in simulation mode to add the table and calculate the number of pages the table is shown on. Now I'm looking for the best way to add a x/n counter for each header.

Example: my header line is "Table about stuff". I calculate, that the table is split across 3 pages. The resulting headers should look like:
"Table about stuff 1/3" for page one,
"Table about stuff 2/3" for page two,
"Table about stuff 3/3" for page three.

What would be the best way to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a cell event.

I don't have a ready made example, but you could compose one yourself by combining the following examples:

In the [MovieCountries1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) example, I solved the "page X of Y" problem. You always know the value of X, but as long as you're still creating the document, you don't know the value of Y (which is the total number of pages). In your case, you have a similar problem. You want to add "part X of Y".

You can achieve this by adding an emptry cell for which you create a custom `PdfPCellEvent`. You can find several examples with cell events by looking for the keywords [PdfPCell > events](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=201) on the official iText site.

Let's take a look at the [RunLengthEvent](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=94) example where we use a custom `PdfPCellEvent` named `PressPreview`:

```
class PressPreview implements PdfPCellEvent {

    public BaseFont bf;

    public PressPreview() throws DocumentException, IOException {
        bf = BaseFont.createFont();
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect,
            PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        cb.beginText();
        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
        cb.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, "PRESS PREVIEW",
            rect.getRight() - 3, rect.getBottom() + 4.5f, 0);
        cb.endText();
    }
}
```

In this example, the text "PRESS PREVIEW" is added to all the cells to which you've added this event like this:

```
PdfPCellEvent press = new PressPreview();
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setCellEvent(press);
```

In your case, you'd add two member-variable to the custom event. One `PdfTemplate` to which you'll write the value of Y. One `int` that keeps track of the number of times the event has been triggered. That's X. When the complete table has been added to the document, you Y will be equal to X and you can fill out this value on the `PdfTemplate`.

Summarized: what you want isn't impossible, but it's not trivial.

Comment: The cell event did the trick. I didn't use a PdfPTemplate, though. I kept a reference to the event and set the total number of pages later. This allows me to make decisions depending on this number, i.e. I don't want to add 1/1 if the table fits on one page.